# Switch red5 https.port

Tags: ssh, https, parallels, plesk, red5

Our Plesk parallels was installed at port 8443 and since installing red5, we haven't had use of it. I later found out that by default, when a server has ssl, red5 uses port 8443. Is there any way to switch this via ssh so I can get parallels back? I have already verified it's still there: I just can't see it.

Does anyone know of a step-by-step guide to make this happen? I can't seem to find anything.

I found this: http://avchathq.com/blog/tag/change-red5-ports/ but I don't really know how to use the info.

Answer (score 0):

The information in this documentation should be correct.

Login to your server via ssh, and go to the conf subdirectory in your red5 installation directory

```
cd /path/to/red5/conf
```

There you should find a file called `red5.properties`. Open it in an editor and change the port configuration according to your needs.

Don't forget to restart red5 afterwards in order to listen on the new port. You will also have to restart Plesk so it can bind to port 8443 again.